# How to Accept Cookies alert with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm trying to get to google.com and type something in the search bar. But the cookies alert pop-up always gets in my way. So I have to click the button 'I agree'. I know I have to wait a little bit of time before searching for the element but even if I'll wait with `WebDriverWait()` function, or `.implicitly_wait()` it just doesn't want to find the element (I used the search by xpath and `.click()` to press the button).
Spent hours trying to find a solution...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    url = 'https://www.google.com/'
    driver.get(url)
 
    # The following line is supposed to wait for the button to appear and then click:
    agreeButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='introAgreeButton']")))
    agreeButton.click()

main()
```

Also i should include the error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "{SCRIPT PATH}", line 49, in <module>
    
     main()

File "{SCRIPT PATH}", line 46, in main

   agreeButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='introAgreeButton']")))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Either you're not waiting long enough, or the xpath is incorrect. Please provide the HTML for further diagnosis.

Comment: There is no html at that link.

Comment: @dmart sorry... it was late night and made a mistake. Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Mh4fYreZRHJ9OcZttTBpF61U24jNMoGydKCgQa2E-HA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: also here is the inspect element html from google, that contains the element I'm looking for: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Dn5fgJUPuTpUl0Xpp-BQ4inC4eCS-QcaCDFkkYikjg8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: honestly, i'm not keen on open random google docs. Would be helpful to provide a link to the site or post the relevant html to your post.

Comment: @DMart I'm sorry I am new to this platform, don't know how all things work. The html is too long, I can't post it in here because I am limited to 500 characters, that's why I put it in docs. The site I'm trying to reach, as shown in code is https://www.google.com/ . Is there any way I could provide you the html, a way that you're comfortable with?